# Destination host unreachable

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan

I have 2 router connected to 1 switch which contains two vlans, 1 router has the ip table of vlan1 and the other router have the ip table of vlan2

I have trunked both router cable to the switch.

I have set 1 ip table per router which correspond to the ip address of the PC that have this router address as a gateway.

When I ping from 192.168.100.2 to 192.168.200.2 it tells me that destination host is unreachable and the message is from the router 192.168.100.1.

So I guess router for 192.168.100.x does not see the router for 192.168.200.x , right ? Or am I wrong ? What are good troubleshooting steps ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tA0p.png is the representation of the network, i cannot post image since im not reputated enough.

Comment: It's hard to formulate any kind of answer without seeing a diagram of the network and without seeing the config of the switch and the routers. Can you post that information?

Answer (score 1):

A good troubleshooting step involves using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on the PCs involved. Is it possible that your having arp issues? Try clearing your [arpcache](http://www.tech-faq.com/clear-arp-cache.html)